# How to get a value between a range of varchar string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to search for a value between two strings that are varchar.

I have two tables:

```
#Code:

StartList   EndList Code
1           3       A
4           7       B
20          25      C
1a          1e      1

#Product:

Product
22
2
1c
```

If I search for product 22 between startlist and end list then I will get two results:

```
StartList   EndList Code    Product
1           3       A       22
20          25      C       22
```

Since its a varchar value, it searched for every string individually. 2 of 22 is between the first row above and 22 is between 20 and 25 on 2nd row. I cannot change the columns to string because it has a varchar value that needs to be search as well. For example: Product 1c should be found in row four of table #code. Any advice on how I can accomplish this so I only get the exact result: Product 22 between 20 and 25, product 2 between 1 and 3, and product 1c between 1a and 1e?

Here is the code I am using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Code') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Code
CREATE TABLE #Code (
     StartList      VARCHAR(10)
    ,EndList        VARCHAR(10)
    ,Code           VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Code(StartList, EndList, Code)
VALUES('1','3','A'),('4','7','B'),('20','25','C'),('1a','1e','1')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Product
CREATE TABLE #Product (
     Product            VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Product(Product)
VALUES('22'),('2'),('1c')

--SELECT    * FROM #Code 
--SELECT    * FROM #Product 

SELECT  * 
FROM #code a
left join #product b on b.product between a.startlist and a.endlist 
where product = '22'
```

Comment: What counts as "between" a `varchar` value? For a `varchar` `'22'` is between `'2'` and `'3'` and `'34'` is "between" `'1'` and `'317'`? You can't expect a `varchar` to order like a numerical value; they are nothing alike.

Comment: Zero-pad the numbers if you want to search them as strings.  Fix the data -- because the semantics of the strings don't work for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend fixing the data to zero-pad the numbers so the values can be correctly compared as strings.

Absent that, though, you could try converting them to numbers:

```
select  * 
from #code c join
     #product p
     on try_convert(int, p.product) between try_convert(int, c.startlist and try_convert(int, c.endlist) or
        (try_convert(int, c.startlist) is null and
         p.product between c.startlist and c.endlist)
where p.product = '22'
```

Comment: Nice, great approach. I have never heard of try_convert. Thanks for the exposure and advice. This is working beautifully. I will have to test further. I appreciate it